# Transmitting a block of memory that has NULL characters to a PHP program from C

Tags: php, c

My C program needs to transmit a block of zlib compressed data from a C program to a PHP program via CURL library. The compressed data seems to have NULL characters in between. I do a memcpy to send the data to PHP program. But, when the data is received in the PHP program, it seems to retrieve only the data until the first NULL character is noticed.

How do I send the block of memory that has such multiple NULL characters and receive it as a whole data in PHP program?

I compress and transmit the data from C program as below:

```
ret = compress (out, &dest_len, str, src_len);
sprintf (output, "data=");
char *temp = output;
temp += 5;
memcpy (temp, out,  dest_len);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/post.php");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, output);
```

From the PHP program, if I dump the data as below, I get only the first block of data, until NULL is encountered. I do not have much knowledge in PHP. Please help out.

Thanks,
Alexander

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the size of the data, otherwise curl will use strlen(). From the curl documentation:

http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html#CURLOPTPOSTFIELDSIZE

CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE

If you want to post data to the server without letting libcurl do a strlen() to measure the data size, this option must be used. When this option is used you can post fully binary data, which otherwise is likely to fail. If this size is set to -1, the library will use strlen() to get the size.

Comment: Thanks. The string seems to have 2 NULL characters. One at 7th and 29th byte. The size of data is 34. After setting this option to specify the size of the data is 34, now PHP program receives the data as 29 bytes. Earlier, it was receiving only 7 bytes. But, still it is not receiving the whole 34 bytes.

Comment: Hmmmm, off by 5 bytes, seems suspiciously like a number already in your program.

Comment: What values are in positions 28, 29, 30? Is there a zero there? Are the first 29 bytes correct?

Comment: You can "check off" my answer to be friendly.

Comment: The problem is I didn't update the dest_len to include the size of "data=".

Answer (score 0):

A string is terminated by the first `nul` character. You need to transmit a binary block of data. You can use the `--data-binary` flag to indicate that "all the data should be sent".